# Display WordPress full content instead post excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display full content instead the post excerpt. I didn't want to modify the theme. I just want to make a plugin where I will put the file.

I found something like this

```
function narga_excerpts($content = false) {
    # If is the home page, an archive, or search results
    if(is_front_page() || is_archive() || is_search()) :
        global $post;
    $content = $post->post_excerpt;
    $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    # If an excerpt is set in the Optional Excerpt box
    if($content) :
        $content = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $content);
    # If no excerpt is set
    else :
        $content = $post->post_content;
    $excerpt_length = 50;
    $words = explode(' ', $content, $excerpt_length + 1);
    if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
        array_pop($words);
    array_push($words, '...<p><a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">  ' . __( 'Read more &#187;', 'narga' ) . ' </a></p>');
    $content = implode(' ', $words);
endif;
$content = '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
endif;
endif;

return $content;
    }

add_filter('the_content', 'narga_excerpts')
```

But it's totally different. The code modify `the_content` to show `the_excerpts`. How can I change the code to display WordPress full content  instead post excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

Using `the_content()` will display the full content of a post.

Changing the function to this should work

```
function narga_excerpts($content = false) 
{
    # If is the home page, an archive, or search results
    if(is_front_page() || is_archive() || is_search()) :
        global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    endif;

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'narga_excerpts')
```